# setState doesn't execute the callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I have a select filter, I want to filter my products by category. The state gets updated but the callback of setState is not executed. Basically I want to update my list immediately when the state is changed. Code line 31 doesn't get executed in the try blok, it's also not catching any error.

HTML

```
<div className="col-md-4 w-25 mt-3 ml-5">
                <Select
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={selectedCategory}
                  placeholder="Select Category"
                  options={categories}
                />
   </div>
```

JavaScript

```
    handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.value);
    this.setState({ selectedCategory: event.value }, () => {
      try {
        products.pipe(
          map(products =>
            products
              .filter(
                product => product.category === this.state.selectedCategory
              )
              .subscribe(products => {
                console.log(products);
                this.setState({
                  items: products,
                  isLoaded: true
                });
              })
          )
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  };
```

[image]

Comment: `this.setState(() => return {}, () => {callback here})`

Comment: It's being executed, but your `this.state` and `this.setState()` are getting the context from the wrong source because you used `function() {` instead of `() => {`

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to accomplish and what is not working. Please update the question description with more details. Also include a [mcve], the code snippet currently in the question is missing a lot of dependencies to be reproducible.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I think it's pretty clear. It _appears_ as if it's not executing because `this` is not what they think it is, so the `.filter()` probably returns `false` for every category.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's still not minimal, but I see now that it's obvious. Missed it while quickly skimming over the code. Though I'm wondering why it's not failing with either `state` or `selectedCategory` not being properties of undefined?

Comment: @EmileBergeron `this` might be `window` and `state` might happen to be a global variable in their application? Just a guess. Another possibility is that rxjs catches the exception thrown in `filter()` and emits an `onerror` message from the observable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  I already tried your solution, but had no luck. I forgot to delete the function before posting it. During debuging it jumps from the code product.pipe oprator and the DOM also doesn't rerender.

Comment: @Muj if it doesn't work for you, then [edit] your question with the code you actually did try as a [mcve] like Emile has requested above, and flag your question to be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick, still don't know why it was not working. Can anybody explain this?

handleChange = event => {

```
      this.setState(
        { selectedCategory: event.value },
        this.showFilteredProducts
      );
  };

  showFilteredProducts() {
    const filterItems = products.pipe(
      map(products =>
        products.filter(
          product => product.category === this.state.selectedCategory
        )
      )
    );
    filterItems.subscribe(products => {
      this.setState({
        items: products,
        isLoaded: true
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.value);
    this.setState({ selectedCategory: event.value }, () => { // this line right here
      products.pipe(
        map(products =>
          products
            .filter(product => product.category === this.state.selectedCategory)
            .subscribe(products => {
              console.log(products);
              this.setState({
                items: products,
                isLoaded: true
              });
            })
        )
      );
    });
  };
```

Change this line: `this.setState({ selectedCategory: event.value }, function() {` to this `this.setState({ selectedCategory: event.value }, () => {`

Calling it 'function' changes the `this` context.

Comment: This is an often-repeated duplicate.

Comment: I already tried your solution, but had no luck. I forgot to delete the function before posting it. During debuging it jumps from the code product.pipe oprator and the DOM also doesn't rerender

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `products.pipe(...)` call in a try-catch to see if it's erroring?